# Converting a 5 digit integer to bytes through a client / server network

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to serialize a 5 digit integers to bytes to be sent across client / server network. I need assistance fixing the function that does that.

Error message:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

My code:

```
import socket
import sys
from io import BytesIO 
import struct

portnum = 5000
hostname = 'localhost'

def int_to_byte(m): 
    (msgtype,content)=m
    buf = BytesIO()
    buf.write(struct.pack('<i',int(content)))
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf.read()

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_addr = (hostname,portnum)
sock.connect(server_addr)
msg = "Hello There!"
numbers = 12345

sock.send(str.encode(msg)) 
sock.send(int_to_byte(numbers)) 

print("Message sent")
sock.close()
```

Comment: You are trying to unpack the integer `12345` as if it were a tuple of two elements on the first line of `def_to_int`, in `(msgtype,content)=m`, which of course can't work...

Comment: How can I fix that ?